# TypeScript/React. ERROR Type '{ key: number; }' is not assignable to type ILink (SFC Component)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

So, I have a basic iterable Component `Link` that render some link. He is wrapped up in `Links` component that iterate him. Unfortunately, the problem that I faced is the `Typescript` does not understand what to do with `key` prop on `Link component` over `Links` Component iteration.

I'll gradeful for any help!

Error message:

> Type '{ key: number; }' is not assignable to type 'ILink'.
>
> Property 'title' is missing in type '{ key: number; }'.

My code:

```
import React from 'react'
import styles from './index.cssmodule.scss'

interface ILinks {
  links: object[]
}

interface ILink {
  title: string
  label: string
  href: string
  icon: string
}

// Link Component
const Link: React.SFC<ILink> = ({ title, label, href, icon }) => (
  <a href={href + label}>
    <i className={icon} />
    <span>{title}</span>
  </a>
)

// Links Component that wraps Link
const Links: React.SFC<ILinks> = ({ links = [] }) => {    
  const bulidLinksList = (): JSX.Element[] => (
    links.map((link, i) => (
      <Link key={i} {...link} /> // ERROR Type '{ key: number; }' is not assignable to type ILink
    ))
  )

  return (
    <div className={styles.linksContainer}>
      {bulidLinksList()}
    </div>
  )
}
   
export default Links
```

Comment: emmm,React may think see the key as a property that should pass to Link.I once face a similar situation, maybe not a good way ,but I add a <div key={i}></div>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `React.ReactElement` instead of `React.SFC`, `ReactElement` will give you `key` and `ref` props

```
const Link: React.ReactElement<ILink> = ({ title, label, href, icon }) => (
  <a href={href + label}>
    <i className={icon} />
    <span>{title}</span>
  </a>
)

// Links Component that wraps Link
const Links: React.ReactElement<ILinks> = ({ links = [] }) => {    
  const bulidLinksList = (): JSX.Element[] => (
    links.map((link, i) => (
      <Link key={i} {...link} />
    ))
  )

  return (
    <div className={styles.linksContainer}>
      {bulidLinksList()}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it work. But in this case I cannot use the `defaultProps` for SFC Components with `React.ReactElement ` invoke type. So, I need some other way to get out from this

Comment: You can combine both types, like this `React.SFCElement<ILink> & React.ReactElement<ILink>`, I researched it and found a lot of people are using that for making their type

Answer (score 1):

You are defining an interface `Link` like that:

```
interface ILink {
  title: string
  label: string
  href: string
  icon: string
}
```

Then you try to assign `key={i}`, which ends up just being an object like

```
{
  key: 123;
}
```

You have not defined `key` in your `ILink` interface. That's why TypeScript complains.

Comment: and by the way, title, lable href and icon are required if you use the interface too.

Comment: Yes, I try that way by explicitly set the `key: number` in  `interface ILink { key: number title: string label: string href: string icon: string }` and I always get the same error...

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem here is that on line  your are not using ReactElement, but function functional interface React.SFC which will produce ReactElement. That fuction expects interface which you defined like this 
interface ILink {
  title: string
  label: string
  href: string
  icon: string
}

Comment: ...and what I should to do?

Comment: You can extend ur interface to contain key and then inside function assign that key to ReactElement "<a href={href + label} key={key}>" in ur case.

Comment: But this will be common problem and extending interface on every place is the easier solution but not the best tho. I recommend declaring new component like this:
const WithKey: React.SFC<{key: string}> = (props) => (
  <div key={props.key}>{props.children}</div>
)
And then use composition of components. You can then reuse this WithKey component on multiple places.

Comment: I am not sure if example will work. I am not able to try it right now. But i hope the idea is clear?